# when saving q table to csv gives type error

Tags: kdb

Hi I have multiple tables which I want to save it to a directory location in csv format.
When I try to save the q table it gives me type error.
I am also looking to make a function out of it so that it can be used to convert the q table to csv and save it to a location.

The meta of table looks like this,

[image]

and the contents looks like, this is just 10 row, whole table is having about 5k rows.

[image]

The code which i am using to try to save is something like

```
    save `res.csv
    `:res.csv 0: "," 0: res
    "," 0: res   //even this also gives error
```

error screen

[image]

The output of -> distinct type''[res] ->is below
[image]

Also, the cols[res] where 1<(count distinct type each)each res cols res -> gives below

```
cols[res] where 1<(count distinct type each)each res cols res
`Actual`Forecast`Previous`FiscalTag`FiscalReference`Currency
```

Comment: Can you include some of the code which is giving you a type error?

Comment: @rianoc, sorry I missed to add that code, I had just updated the code in the question itself. Basically I tried using save operator and even 0:

Comment: Is your first code block the result of `meta res`? (It seems unlikely so many columns have char type. Also the column names do not match the displayed table.) Could you replace the last code block with an extract from your console showing the save expression and the error response?

Comment: I had used screenshots in the desc question, it should look better now.

Comment: That makes it clear that the error is being signalled by [Prepare Text](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#prepare-text); so the question is: what causes `","0:` to signal a type error with a table right argument.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `distinct type''[res]` .... that's often a good starting point for finding table inconsistencies

Comment: sure, let me add the output of distinct type''[res] to the end of question.

Comment: @terrylynch ok, i was able to fix those column by casting it.

`res:update Actual:{$[(type x)=0h;"";x]}'[Actual],Forecast:{$[(type x)=0h;"";x]}'[Forecast],Previous:{$[(type x)=0h;"";x]}'[Previous],FiscalTag:{$[(type x)=-9h;"";x]}'[FiscalTag],FiscalReference:{$[(type x)=-9h;"";x]}'[FiscalReference],Currency:{$[(type x)=-9h;"";x]}'[Currency] from res;`

That was a very cleaver trick with `distinct type''[res]`, thank you very much for sharing that. How can we find such things?

Comment: You just discover them over many years! It wouldn't scale very well for large tables but was fine for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prepare Text](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#prepare-text) signals a type error if a table column is neither a vector nor a list of strings.

```
q)t:([]i:6 7 8;Actual:1.47 0.03 300;FiscalTag:("FY2022Q2";"FY2022Q2";enlist"FY2022H1"))

q)t
i Actual FiscalTag
--------------------
6 1.47   "FY2022Q2"
7 0.03   "FY2022Q2"
8 300    ,"FY2022H1
q)csv 0: t
'type
  [0]  csv 0: t
           ^
```

Sadly [`meta`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/meta/) won’t diagnose this condition. It examines only the first row of `t`.

```
q)meta t
c        | t f a
---------| -----
i        | j
Actual   | f
FiscalTag| C
```

`type each` is your friend.

```
q)cols[t] where 1<(count distinct type each)each t cols t
,`FiscalTag
```

I have revised the Reference article on Prepare Text to warn about the issue.

Comment: In hindsight, the slight offsets of the `FiscalTag` values in rows 7 8 were a visual clue.

Comment: okay the type each worked like a charm, it gave the possible column names which needs to be fixed.
Now we have the column names, how do we fix the identified columns?

Comment: ok, i was able to fix those column by casting it.
`res:update Actual:{$[(type x)=0h;"";x]}'[Actual],Forecast:{$[(type x)=0h;"";x]}'[Forecast],Previous:{$[(type x)=0h;"";x]}'[Previous],FiscalTag:{$[(type x)=-9h;"";x]}'[FiscalTag],FiscalReference:{$[(type x)=-9h;"";x]}'[FiscalReference],Currency:{$[(type x)=-9h;"";x]}'[Currency] from res;`

Comment: Besides the fix, think about how the rogue lists got into the table columns – a join or update with an `enlist` too far somewhere? Maybe because of using char datatype where symbol would be usual.

Comment: I am calling the https api and it return type json back from a vendor and got back those type in kdb by default and i did below.
`raw:@[.Q.hg;q;{[error] .lg.o[queryfail; error];}];` and then `res:@[.j.k;raw;{[error] .lg.o[queryfail; error];}];`